# CFG Error email receiving every 5 minutes from Zabbix on Unix server

Tags: email, gmail, zabbix, mailx, ssmtp

I have configured **sSMTP** on **myzabbixserver** Unix system which successfully delivers Zabbix alerts via Gmail. Strangely I am receiving an email in my Gmail **inbox** (which I am using as From address for sSMTP config) **EVERY 5 minutes** with following details:

```
from: root <my.zabbix@gmail.com> 
to: root
bcc: my.zabbix@gmail.com
subject: Cron <root@myzabbixserver> if [ -x /usr/bin/mrtg ] && [ -r /etc/mrtg.cfg ]; then mkdir -p /var/log/mrtg ; env LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg /etc/mrtg.cfg 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/mrtg/mrtg.log ; fi

body: ERROR: CFG Error in "workdir", line 8: Working directory /var/www/mrtg does not exist
```

sSTMP.conf

```
root=my.zabbix@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

AuthUser=my.zabbix@gmail.com
AuthPass=my.password

hostname=myzabbixserver
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthMethod=LOGIN
```

**gmail.sh** script which Zabbix uses to send email alerts:

```
#!/bin/bash
to=$1
subject=$2
body=$3
echo $body | /usr/bin/mailx $to -s "$subject"
```

What does that email mean and how can I stop it ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with zabbix or gmail or email or mailx or ssmtp. you have a problem with mrtg. Don't even read the error message?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Zabbix problem, but mrtg problem. Your mrtg cron job /etc/cron.d/mrtg is failing and you are receiving this cron error output.

Solutions:

- configure mrtg correctly (http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mrtg.htm)
- uninstall mrtg/disable mrtg cron job
- ...